# Can you refresh a SSRS report from self contained code?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Hi I am making a report that has a few drill through reports on it.  Some of them have a median calculation that is being generated by an array that is populated when SSRS generates the report.  The problem I am having is when someone navigates 'Back' to a report from one of the drillthroughs is that since the array is no longer valid the median calc does not work.  This is not a parameter, but a Code function.  All the paremeters are passing back and forth just fine.

I have a bypass in right now to check for this condition and display Re-Calc in the textbox, but what I really want is to do is when this condition occurs trigger a re-generation of the report.

I have been searching around on the internet and not found any viable solutions yet.

I do not want AutoRefresh.  I am looking for something to add into the Report Code, or an Expression, to trigger a Refresh of the report.  I can already identify when I need it to happen in code, I just need the command to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by "Registered User" is pretty close to what I think will work. However, if you use the default GUI drill-through option in SSRS, it may not always completely reload the report, which might account for what you're finding.

If you use the "Go to URL" option in the Action tab (instead of the "Go to Report" option), you cause the browser to reload everything. My anecdotal explanation is that when you use the "Go to Report" option, you're moving around within the ReportViewer framework and so it may be using some cache to regenerate parts of your report. When you use the "Go to URL" option, I believe it forces your browser to leave the current page and re-enter the destination page.

[This](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/7/25/using-an-ssrs-url-which-does-not-display-breadcrumbs.html) link has good information on report server paths and how to manipulate the URL to control how your page feels.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188712.aspx) is a resource on all the different URL parameters you can use in the "Go to URL" option to control how your page is loaded and what parameters are passed through.

To use the Go to URL option, you can use the global ReportServer & ReportFolder fields so you're not typing in the full address each time. Also, if you want to make sure your parameter bar always shows up (which is what I'm guessing you're referring to by "selection boxes"), you can use the rs:Parameters=true URL parameter. FYI, one of the other great things about the "Go to URL" option is that you can integrate all SSRS functions and some limited JavaScript to really control where and how your page goes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What I wound up doing was removing the calculation within the SSRS tablix and instead populating the data into a dataset on it's own. More cumbersome, but it yielded the desired visuals.

Comment: I've run into similar (not the same, but similar) issues before, and I've always just ended up not using custom code. From what I've seen, a lot of people do the same thing. I've found few references to people running into problems with custom code and finding a suitable solution using custom code.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution that doesn't fully meet your requirements is add a link back to the report on the drill through report.  You could pass the parameters back to the original report when you click on the link and it would rerender the report.  It won't help users who hit the back button, but it will get you a slightly better user experience.  You could even create a link to the report again on the fields that display ReCalc so that they don't have to hit refresh.

Someone asked a question kind of similar to yours on [another forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/231a371a-436c-48a4-8e87-a936e048d8fb/how-to-refresh-a-report-in-microsoft-sql-server-reporting-services-from-a-custom-code).  The solution seems like overkill to me.  I'd recommend using the above solution combined with training users to click the link to go back instead of clicking the back button.

Comment: yeah I ran into that post in my researcht, and I am aware of the idea to put in a navigate back button. But when you do that if you pass parameters you do not get the selection boxes, if you do not pass paremeters the report is blank and you have re-populate your paremeter choices before running the report. Neither fits the functionality I desire. Even when I put this up as a bounty I suspected what I want is not possible without wrapping this into a .NET web app, instead of just SSRS. Just looking for some clarity from the wizards out there. =)